# TestNG is not running in parallel in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, parallel-processing, testng

My colleague and I are working on this project using TestNG.
We are using data provider and @ factory. The code runs in parallel in his system and it does not in my system! Same code!

Only difference is he uses netBeans and I am using eclipse. I have installed the TestNG plugin. I am able to run the test, but its not in parallel in eclipse. The same code runs in parallel in his netBeans.

Any ideas as to how I can make my code run in parallel in Eclipse ?

Comment: What is the error are you facing? Please place the details error here.

Comment: The "error" is that the code isn't running in parallel

Comment: Related question: [java - How to run TestNG tests in parallel using Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353447).