# How to run TestNG tests in parallel using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, testng

I am new to test-ng, I am using eclipse plugin to run test cases. 
I have an excel file for data. when I am running, it is executing 1 by 1. I know we can execute parallel through `cmd` by setting `parallel="methods" thread-count="2"`, But it not working in Eclipse plugin. So please tell me how to run TestNG parallel in Eclipse.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems here is the exact question and the answer to it:

> When you are running an XML file, you can specify all the settings you want for this run in the XML file, but what if you want to run a package in parallel mode with specific listeners? How can you configure the settings for all the launches that are not done from an XML file?
>
> In order to give you access to the most flexibility, TestNG lets you specify an XML suite file for all these launches, which you can find in the Preferences menu: [screenshot](http://testng.org/doc/pics/template.png).
>
> If you specify a valid suite file as "XML template file", TestNG will reuse all the settings found in this XML file, such as parallel, name, listeners, thread pool size, etc... Only the `<test>` tags in this file will be ignored since the plug-in will replace these by a generated `<test>` tag that represents the launch you chose.
>
> — [TestNG - Eclipse](http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html).

Long story short, it is necessary to have the suite XML file.

Also, please see the documentation on the appropriate part of the suite XML file schema: [TestNG: 5.10 - Parallelism and time-outs](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running).